# Format seconds into the two biggest units of time

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, formatting

I wrote a function to convert seconds into the two biggest units of time and format it into a string. What I mean is that e.g. 134 second would be `02m14s` and 3665 seconds would become `1h1m`. Here is what I did:

```
def pprint_time(seconds):
    m, s = divmod(seconds, 60)
    h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    d, h = divmod(h, 24)
    format_str = lambda v1, v2, p: f"{v1:0>2}{p[0]}{v2:0>2}{p[1]}"
    if d > 0:
        return format_str(d, h, ("d","h"))
    elif h > 0:
        return format_str(h, m, ("h","m"))
    elif m > 0:
        return format_str(m, s, ("m","s"))
    else:
        return f" {s:0>2}sec"
```

I wonder if there is a more "pythonic" way of doing this since the `if-elif-else` statement does feel a bit clunky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general I think your code is pretty good.  It is a simple function, and it does not need to get fancy.

I do think one bit could be a bit cleaner.  I believe this format string:

```
format_str = lambda v1, v2, p: f"{v1:0>2}{p[0]}{v2:0>2}{p[1]}"
format_str(d, h, ("d","h"))
```

would be simpler and therefore clearer as:

```
format_str = "{:0>2}{}{:0>2}{}"
format_str.format(d, 'd', h, 'h')
```

I think the `lambda` here is not helping readability.

### More Pythonic?

For this simple case I don't think you really need anything more Pythonic.  But let's have some fun and illustrate using some Python libraries.

#### `datetime` library

First thing to consider is maybe using standard Python lib for doing some of the date and time math. The library could build those values for you like so:

```
import datetime as dt

# build a datetime from the number of seconds passed in
a_time = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds)

# get d, h, m, s
d, h, m, s = dt.timedelta(seconds=seconds).days, a_time.hour, a_time.minute, a_time.second
```

#### Stacked ifs

You asked specifically about the stacked ifs. In this case the ifs are not stacked very deep, so what follows is rather severe overkill :-)

Here is a general way to get the elements following the first non-zero element.

```
# get values fllowing first non zero value and their labels
non_zero = tuple(it.dropwhile(lambda x: not x[0], zip(values, 'dhms')))
```

Yikes, this is that an eyesore! But is does show how to get the elements following the first non-zero element in a general way, IE: No stacked ifs needed.

#### How does that work?

Let's break it down a bit.  Starting from the inside:

```
zip(values, 'dhms')
```

This will produce a sequence of tuples looking something like:

```
[(0, 'd'), (1, 'h'), (1, 'm'), (5, 's')]
```

Note how the use of `zip()` allows the labels to be associated with their elements.  This allows the next step to keep the labels with their values.

Then:

```
it.dropwhile(lambda x: not x[0], zip(values, 'dhms')))
```

uses [`itertools.dropwhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) to drop the leading tuples which start with `0`. Finally:

```
non_zero = tuple(it.dropwhile(lambda x: not x[0], zip(values, 'dhms')))
```

will produce a tuple so that we can get the number of elements to help produce the format string:

```
# a format string
format_str = "{:0>2}{}{:0>2}{}" if len(non_zero) > 1 else " {:0>2}sec"
```

And then bring it all together with:

```
# format the string
return format_str.format(*it.chain.from_iterable(non_zero or ((0, 0),)))
```

[`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) flattens the `non_zero` tuple, to make the `format()` a little easier:

#### Complete recast function

```
import datetime as dt
import itertools as it

def pprint_time2(seconds):

    # build a datetime from the number of seconds passed in
    a_time = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds)

    # get d, h, m, s
    values = dt.timedelta(seconds=seconds).days, a_time.hour, a_time.minute, a_time.second

    # get values following first non zero value and their labels
    non_zero = tuple(it.dropwhile(lambda x: not x[0], zip(values, 'dhms')))

    # a format string
    format_str = "{:0>2}{}{:0>2}{}" if len(non_zero) > 1 else " {:0>2}sec"

    # format the string
    return format_str.format(*it.chain.from_iterable(non_zero or ((0, 0),)))
```

Comment: Thanks just what I was looking for! I know that my function isn't really that cumbersome but I just wanted to know if there was some shorter (albeit maybe dumber) way of doing it. Just for fun and for the future.